# How to create this calculator without using conditionals or loops

Tags: java, scala, class, methods

I want to create a calculator in Scala and I need to incorporate the decimal action and the addition action. The addition action will need to override the previous operator action, so if the user presses [4, -, +, 2, =], this will return 6. The thing is that both actions has to executed without the use of conditionals such as match/case or loops.How do I do this? Here is what I attempted.

```
import javafx.event.{ActionEvent, EventHandler}

class Calculator(){
    //this is what will appear on the calculator
    def displayNumber(): Double={
        0.0
    }

class DecimalAction(calculator: Calculator) extends EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
  calculator.displayNumber() = calculator.displayNumber() + ".".toInt
}
}

class AdditionAction(calculator: Calculator) extends EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
    override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
      calculator.displayNumber() = calculator.displayNumber() + "+".toInt
}
}
```

Comment: "Have to be executed without conditionals"? 
[XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) ...

Comment: Yes, this a part of the task in which I have to apply object-orientation programming.

Comment: Arbitrarily avoiding use of  parts of the language is has nothing to do with "object-oriented programming".

Comment: @Dima Homework questions are on-topic, and this question sounds like a great way to learn about [dynamic dispatch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon ok. I can't wait to see you implement it without use of conditionals. Should be fun!

Comment: @Dima I wrote a sketch of a solution showing how to use dynamic dispatch to avoid conditionals. I will say that the question may be unclear or too broad...

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon there is no `String` or `Char` mentioned anywhere in your sketch. I was curious to see how you were planning to go from "4 - + 6" to `Add(4, Seq(6))` without using conditionals ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your calculator class, you need to keep track of which operation will happen next, if any.

```
var nextOperation: Optional[Operation] = None
```

I'll define `Operation` below. In your action classes, you can then set `nextOperation`, overriding it if it's already set to something else.

```
class DecimalAction(calculator: Calculator) extends EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
  override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
    calculator.nextOperation = Some(Decimal)
  }
}

class AdditionAction(calculator: Calculator) extends EventHandler[ActionEvent] {
  override def handle(event: ActionEvent): Unit = {
    calculator.nextOperation = Some(Add)
  }
}
```

Now, we define `Operation` as a sealed trait with a `combine` method that does the work of adding, subtracting, or decimal-joining two numbers. When you call `combine` on an `Operation`, it will use [dynamic dispatch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) instead of conditionals to pick the right method.

```
sealed trait Operation {
  /** Combine the existing number with the new digits under the current operation. */
  def combine(x: Double, y: Seq[Int]): Double
}

case object Decimal extends Operation {
  def combine(x: Double, y: Seq[Int]) = ???
}

case object Add extends Operation {
  def combine(x: Double, y: Seq[Int]) = ???
}
```

The rest will depend on how exactly you want your calculator implemented, but you're probably going to have to think some about order of operations (e.g. decimal will probably have precedence over addition).